# How might someone view the balance of a multisig monero address without both its private keys?

Tags: viewkey, privatekey, multisig

Is it possible? Would two view keys allow you to at least see what it had received? Would one view key? Not sure how multisig would work with Monero. Perhaps there would only be one view key?

Answer (score 1):

There is no Multisig right now for Monero and it still on research. Based on the milestone [here](https://forum.getmonero.org/8/funding-required/87059/shen-noether-ringct-review-multisig-design-and-implementation) its not yet complete.

However, if you are asking how the multisig works when it is implemented I don't know either. The [post proposing the multisig](https://shnoe.wordpress.com/2016/03/22/ring-multisignature/) is not available anymore.

Comment: The internet doesn't forget that easy... http://web.archive.org/web/20161023005318/https://shnoe.wordpress.com/2016/03/22/ring-multisignature/